# Can't reach login after Ubuntu 18.04 "Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found"

Tags: login, 18.04, lvm

When I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and rebooted I had the "Failed to start session" error. Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+alt+<kbd>f1</kbd> I found myself in a terminal, and used `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`, then rebooted.

After entering my encryption pass, I see this error:

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: recovering journal
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 487053/30203904 files, 66914067/120783872 blocks
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Reading all physical volumes. THis may take a while...
Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: recovering journal
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 487053/30203904 files, 66914067/120783872 blocks
```

This message is shown for 1-4 seconds, after that it just goes black and then it shows the same message again. Nothing happens when I press anything, except if I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd> (or similar) the login terminal can be seen briefly, before going completely black and continuing the loop.

I'm new to Ubuntu. How can I solve this?

Comment: It is because LVM is not loading.  Take a look here fro some solutions. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1573982